# How do you create multiple dropdown boxes in Java? I want to add another drop down box after these lines of code

Tags: javascript, java

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Recipes"); 
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setLocation(430, 100);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    frame.add(panel);

    JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Select time taken");
    lbl.setVisible(true);

    panel.add(lbl);

    String[] choices = { "10 MINS","15 MINS", "20 MINS","25 MINS","30 MINS"};

    final JComboBox<String> cb = new JComboBox<String>(choices);

    cb.setVisible(true);
    panel.add(cb);
    
    JButton btn = new JButton("OK");
    panel.add(btn);`
```

I don't know what to add after this, I tried adding another label and combobox but it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that `frame.setVisible(true);` is in the last line

```java
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Recipes"); 
        //frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setLocation(430, 100);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        frame.add(panel);

        JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Select time taken");
        lbl.setVisible(true);

        panel.add(lbl);

        String[] choices = { "10 MINS","15 MINS", "20 MINS","25 MINS","30 MINS"};

        final JComboBox<String> cb = new JComboBox<String>(choices);

        cb.setVisible(true);
        panel.add(cb);
        
        JButton btn = new JButton("OK");
        panel.add(btn);
        
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```